# Read integer from text file and replace with different integer

Tags: vbscript

I'm working with the below code

```
Dim objFSO, objFile, maxRetry, numRetries, newRetries
CONST ForReading = 1
CONST ForWriting = 2


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(MICacheFilename(), ForReading)
maxRetry = CInt(MIGetTaskParam("maxRetry"))

strText = objFile.ReadAll

Set numRetries  = CInt(objFile.ReadLine)
IF numRetries >= maxRetry THEN
    MISetTaskParam "RerunTask", "False"
    strLine = Replace(strLine,numRetries ,0)
Else
    MISetTaskParam "RerunTask", "True"
    Set newRetries = numRetries + 1
    strLine = Replace(strLine,numRetries ,newRetries)
END IF
```

`MICacheFilename()` and `MIGetTaskParam` are passed into the script as a file path and an integer. My goal is to compare the max value passed in to the value in the file and set `MISetTaskParam` based on the comparison. I'm very new to VB and this seems like it shoudl be easier than I'm finding. The input file is a text file that only contains an integer.

While my first instinct would be to stay in a loop this script is only called periodically and needs to be an IF.

I am currently getting the error `object requried` with `set numRetries  = CInt(objFile.ReadLine)`

Comment: You shouldn't be doing **both** `objFile.ReadLine` and `objFile.ReadAll`. Also, can you redesign the file format to use, say, XML? If so, the problem becomes much easier with `Microsoft.XMLDOM` and `XPATH` queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mhopkins321, you say:

> I am currently getting the error **object requried** with `set numRetries =
>   CInt(objFile.ReadLine)`

That is because the `Set` keyword is used *only* for setting a variable that holds an instance of an **object**. In your case, the purpose `numRetries` is to hold an **integer**.

So, try this instead:

```vb
numRetries = CInt(objFile.ReadLine)
```

I found a few other issues with your script. Here is my edited version with some comments:

```vb
Option Explicit  ' Checks that you have declared all variables

Dim objFSO, objFile, maxRetry, numRetries, newRetries
Dim strText, strLine  ' declare these also
CONST ForReading = 1
CONST ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(MICacheFilename(), ForReading)
maxRetry = CInt(MIGetTaskParam("maxRetry"))

' strText = objFile.ReadAll  ' Not needed

numRetries = CInt(objFile.ReadLine)  ' just read the one line in the file
WScript.Echo "numRetries = [" & numRetries & "]"
IF numRetries >= maxRetry THEN
    MISetTaskParam "RerunTask", "False"
    strLine = Replace(strLine,numRetries ,0)  ' does nothing, 'strline' is empty
Else
    MISetTaskParam "RerunTask", "True"
    newRetries = numRetries + 1
    strLine = Replace(strLine,numRetries ,newRetries)  ' does nothing, 'strline' is empty
END IF

WScript.Echo "strLine = [" & strLine & "]"

' Dummy Function.
Function MICacheFilename()
    MICacheFilename = "retries.txt"
End Function

' Dummy Function.
Function MIGetTaskParam(key)
    MIGetTaskParam = 13
End Function

' Dummy Sub.
Sub MISetTaskParam(arg1, arg2)
End Sub
```